# How much natural background radiation is there at 5g radio frequencies?

Tags: rf

I'm wondering how much energy at 5g frequencies we are exposed to from natural sources such as sunlight compared to what we might receive from living in a city that has 5g cell towers.

Comment: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/meteo300/node/683

Answer (score 11):

"5G frequencies" do not exist.

5G is just a marketing term. All LTE things after release 14 (I think) is called 5G. So, your LTE base station, if it had a software update, is a 5G station, occupying the exact same spectrum as before.

So, there's potentially 5G wherever you find LTE; depending on your country, that might be somewhere between 800 MHz and 3000 MHz. You'll have to consult with your mobile network operator to learn which bands they bought a license to operate in and are using.

You practically get no background radiation on microwave frequencies. Receiver noise is practically always dominated by receiver-side Johnson-Nyquist noise.

We can compare a lot of the LTE frequencies with what they were used for before reassignment: TV whitespace. Now, a typical TV transmitter has some 75 to 200 kW of power, and around 6 dBi of gain (so it doesn't illuminate the sky). The rest is free-space path loss. A LTE base station doesn't have a constant transmit power, but transmit as much as necessary to each phone as necessary to deliver the quality of service it needs. That means it transmits 0 W to maybe 500 W. I don't have actual numbers – the power budget of base stations is what makes up a significant (if not the most significant) part of the cost of operating a cellular network, and operators tend to be a bit tightly knit when it comes to their business calculations, as that's knowledge that their competitors could use to push exactly into the niches that they don't fully occupy.

ATSC assumes a minimum of -68 dBm received power at the TV for minimal functionality. NTSC/PAL/SECAM is practically more in the -55 dBm range. Notice that this is a continuous illumination; you're constantly exposed to that.

LTE works with -100 dBm quite solidly. For higher rates, bursts of -70 dBm to -50 dBm are desirable. But this is only when there's acute usage. And of course, the cell phone's transmit power in your hand totally trumps your received signal power (for obvious distance reasons):

The square power law applies; if your signal has to reach further by a factor of \$x\$ while maintaining identical receive power, your transmit power has to go up by \$x^2\$.

Corollary, the more cell towers a populated area has, the lower the average person's exposure: to deliver a fixed signal quality, the transmitter has to use quadratically less power, the closer the communication partner is. This applies to both handset and tower.

---

Aside from the minor technical changes with respect to the wave form between 4G and 5G, there's also the practically nowhere deployed 5G NR (new radio), a standard that specifies optional connectivity on a ca 60 GHz carrier.

That's not something you'll find on a cell tower - 60 GHz really propagates pretty much like light, is heavily attenuated by atmosphere and especially atmospheric moisture, so it's not technology that's useful to mount on a tower. It's for indoor and subway / street "canyon" situations. Powers are in the regions you'd call "laughably low", think nanowatts emitted power. Building efficient 60 GHz amplifiers is still a hard task.

Also, I know not a single person that has a phone that has a phone that supports 60 GHz yet.

Comment: Good answer! There's a great deal of marketing distortion of facts surrounding 4G and 5G (e.g., LTE in Release 8 and 9, still did not meet the ITU requirements for 4G as specified in IMT-Advanced; only in Release 10, they cooked up a configuration, the UE Capability 8, to maximize data rate in an impractical combination of carrier aggregation, etc., to show that on paper, Release 10 met the requirements for 4G). However, LTE and 5G are not considered the same system (at least, not by the standards group 3GPP).

Comment: Even in Release 15, whose major work items were on introducing the 5G system, including 5G-NR, there are also a few work items on "LTE enhancements" covering enhancements to LTE systems, such as enhancements to Coordinated MultiPoint (CoMP) in LTE systems. So, work on LTE enhancements continue, and existing operator deployments of LTE systems do not suddenly become 5G systems just because they LTE base stations deploy a software update, etc. The GSM Suppliers Association provides stats on LTE and 5G deployments, and these show hundreds of LTE deployments and only dozens of 5G as of today.

Comment: A similar thing happened between 3G/UMTS and LTE. Even thought LTE was introduced in 3GPP Release 8, work on HSPA that had begun in Release 5, 6 and 7, continued with further enhancements in Release 8, 9, etc., and HSPA networks continued to be called HSPA networks, even as LTE networks begun to be separately deployed.

Comment: 5G has its own air interface, called 5G-NR, and also network architecture. 5G base stations are called gNBs, whereas LTE ones are called eNBs. It is not a simple software update to transform an eNB to a gNB. the 5G network introduces concepts of Network Functions Virtualization, network slicing, etc., to support whole new areas of usage, specifically, massive Machine Type Comms (mMTC) and Ultra Reliable Low Latency Comms (URLLC).

Answer (score 4):

Having studied HAM literature intensely as a kid, the low HAM band noise floors are SET BY THE SUN. Only above 30MHz (10 meters), is thermal noise the floor.
This made the Citizen Band cross-country games of 1970s so feasible.

Regarding 60GHz, assuming some MINO array of antennas with gain of 12dB (2 * 2 * 2 * 2). And 40,000,000 bits per second with 4 bits per symbol (non_OFDM, just regular 16QAM).

Budget at receiver

- -174 dBm/rtHz random electron (Boltzmann) noise floor
- -12 dB receiver/handset phased_array (improves the power margin by +12 dB)
- +4 dB Noise Figure of those 16 receiver channels, with input matching losses and ESD losses and spectral filtering (to exclude some EMI to improve blocking);
  note the 4dB may not be possible at 60GHz.
- +5 dB preferred Signal Noise Ratio
- +70dB for the 10,000,000 symbols per second

---

-107dBm at the handset

Now for the transmitted power:

We'll assume line-of-sight, no multipathing, 5mm wavelength(60GHz), and 50 meter distance across a large hotel ballroom under Moscone Center.

The ratio of distance/wavelength is the most important factor, particularly because of Range^2 energy spreading. We have 50,000 mm / 5 mm == 10,000 wavelengths.

PathLoss is 22dB + 10 * log10[ (distance/wavelength)^2 ]

PathLoss is 22 + 80 === 102 dB. For 50 meter range, at 60GHz.

We'll assume antenna gain of 12dB (as we did for the receiver, and assume 2dB loss in skin_effect of the antenna metal; receiver antenna likely has the same loss.).

TX Power?

- -107dBm at the Receiver antenna
- +102dB Path Loss
- -10dB (-12 + 2) benefit of the MIMO antennas

---

approximately -15dBm (0.03 milliWatts), again assuming free-space across a ballroom, no multipathing

[ you are welcome, Marcus.]

Comment: love the actual link budget!